# Ada: Why does my queue only hold it's value value in the loop?

Tags: ada

So I'm compiling Ada with the Gnat compiler. I have a queue that is holding a record and one of the records variables is an Unbounded_String called name. That is what I'm testing right now although all the records variables should be accessible outside of the loop. The code I'm having issues with is

```
with ada.text_io, stacks, queues, ada.Strings.Unbounded, ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO, ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use ada.Text_IO, ada.Strings.Unbounded, ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO, ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure eliminate is
   type person is record
    index: Positive;
    age: Positive;
      skill: natural;
      wins: natural;
      loss: natural;
      name: Unbounded_String;
   end record;

   package stkPkg is new stacks(person);
   use stkPkg;
   output: Stack;

   package quePkg is new Queues(person);
   use quePkg;
   noLossQ : Queue;

   count : Positive := 1;
   input : Person;       
begin
   while not end_of_file loop
      input.name := get_line;   
      get(input.skill);
      get(input.age);
      skip_line;

      input.index := count;
      count := count + 1;
      input.wins := 0;
      input.loss := 0;
      enqueue(input, noLossQ);
      put_line(front(noLossQ).name);
   end loop;
   put_line(front(noLossQ).name);
end eliminate;
```

If you run it you'll notice that inside the loop put_line(front(noLossQ).name) works just fine, but once outside the loop it does nothing or prints a blank line. The end of the loop where the put_line worked, the loop ended, and then put_line doesn't work; that code follows.

```
   enqueue(input, noLossQ);
   put_line(front(noLossQ).name);
end loop;
put_line(front(noLossQ).name);
```

Here is my Queue implementation

```
with Unchecked_Deallocation, ada.Text_IO;
use ada.Text_IO;
package body queues is
    function is_Empty (Q: Queue) return Boolean is
    begin
        return ((Q.front = null) and (Q.back = null));
    end is_Empty;

    procedure Dequeue (Q : in out Queue) is
    begin
       if is_Empty(Q) then
          raise Queue_Empty;
       else
          Q.Back := Q.Back.Next;
          if Q.Back = null then
             Q.Front := null;
          end if;

       end if;
    end Dequeue;

    procedure Enqueue (Item: ItemType; Q: in out Queue) is
       tmp : QueueNodePointer := new QueueNode'(Item, null);
    begin
        if is_Full(q) then
            raise Queue_Full;
        else
          if Q.Back = Null then
             Q.Back := tmp;
          end if;
          if Q.Front /= null then
             q.front.next := tmp;
          end if;
          q.Front := tmp;
        end if;
    end Enqueue;

    function Front (Q: Queue) return ItemType is
    begin
        if is_Empty(Q) then
           raise Queue_Empty;
        else
           return Q.back.data;
        end if;
    end Front;
end queues;
```

redirected file I'm using:

```
Person one
            500 50 
Person 2 
            400 50 
Person 3
            300 50 
Person 4
            200 50 
Person 5 
            100 50
```

I can't figure out why it only works in the loop, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where are you getting the input from?  A file, or the console?

Comment: Make sure your program isn't raising an End_Error exception.

Comment: Can’t run it because you haven’t included `queues.ads`. Also, `Front` returns `Q.back.data` which is at the very least confusing!

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, but I'm redirecting from a text file I'll add that file to the original post above.

Comment: You really need to **include queues.ads**. And the implementation of Is_Full.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem must be in your queue implementation.  You should test it properly, to ensure that it holds the properties you expect of it.